# Add new Blazor server side app with old Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

I have created a new Blazor server Application and it looks amazing. I have a old Asp.Net application where I want to migrate this Blazor app. Is there anyway, I can do this?

My ASP.NET app is build on .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Can I inject the service into the Component inside .net framework application?

Can I call a Component from the ASP.NET link (or from menu items)?

Kind Regards

Shuvra

Answer (score 2):

Blazor Server doesn't run on .NET Framework, so it can't be in the same IIS site. You will have to host it in a separate site, or as a virtual application in IIS, with that virtual application running on .NET Core.

Comment: Hi mason, Thanks for the reply. I have library written on .Net Framework 4.7.1 (from connection of database and so no..). I like to create a Blazor App that will use the .net framwork library. is It possible?

Comment: @Shuvra Retarget that library to use .NET Standard. There's not a whole lot of reasons a class library should be targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core right now. A library written in .NET Standard can be referenced from .NET Core or .NET Framework.